# How do I restore the default cursor in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: mouse, cursor, 16.10

I performed an upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10.

I do wonder why the mouse cursor is changing between two different themes:

[image: GIF animation]

Comment: Which display manager were you using? The other mouse cursor is Breeze-Dark, and comes will KDE plasma framework 5. have you installed SDDM ?

Comment: I am using the default lightdm manager. SDDM is not installed.

Comment: @Anwar please see my update.

Comment: Do you have other Desktop Environment installed? What are they?

Comment: I don't think I have any other DE installed. How could I check that?

Comment: You can see session selection option in lightdm.

Comment: Thanks, @Anwar! I had the Plasma desktop installed. Removing this restored the white mouse cursor. :-)

Comment: There should be better solutions to this. Plasma DE can happily co-exists with Unity. You could even removed the cursors. But if you think you solved the problem, you can close the question or write your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I restored the default Ubuntu 16.10 cursor by removing all Desktop Environments but Unity 7.5:

```
$ sudo apt remove gnome-shell unity8 plasma-workspace
```